# I want to push a button in my app and as a result automatic start of google maps

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

In my app i have a address and a GPS location and want to start googlemaps with both locations so he can calculate route. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google Maps responds to the `ACTION_VIEW` intent. You can construct a uri with your longitude + latitude and start the activity:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:0.00000,0.00000");
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

The user would have the choice to open this intent in their preferred mapping application.

It might be better to use the full maps.google.com uri instead of this custom one, then the user would open Google Maps in the browser even if they don't have the app installed.

If you want to remove this choice you can use `Intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps")` to suggest the Maps application, but you should check for the existence of this app first.